# Data model tool to connect to Databricks or Data lake

Tags: azure, databricks, data-modeling, entity-relationship, azure-data-lake

From data modeling documentation (Dimensional/ ER Diagram) is there any tool available which can connect to databricks/ data lake and read the table structure directly and also updates the structure of table whenever there is a addition or deletions of columns in a table?

And in a process, it should not remove the relationship made between tables whenever there is an update to a columns and/ or tables (addition/ deletion). And version control on same will be helpful using GIT etc.

Reason being I understand the PK and FK details are not maintained in datalake/ databricks tables entities. Request to please propose if any modeling tools are present for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DBSchema can be used as solution to connect to Databricks tables to do any modeling documentation Relationship Diagrams (https://dbschema.com/)